# Conforming to UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDatasource in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am learning swift 2.0, and I was wondering if you still need to add the code `tableView.datasource = self` and `tableView.delegate = self` like in Obj-C to conform to the protocols?

Example code:

```
class AboutViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,   UITableViewDelegate
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // conform to protocols
        aboutTableView.dataSource = self
        aboutTableView.delegate = self
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 50
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

Now the table view loads with the correct data in each cell.

However, if I remove `aboutTableView.datasource = self` and `aboutTableView.delegate = self` from `viewDidLoad`, my table view is blank. Why is this?

Is this code still required because I see many youtube tutorials that does not include this anymore in swift, and I'm confused as to why mine doesn't work without it?

Comment: That is language independent. – But note that the situation is slightly different if you have a UIViewController or a UITableViewController subclass. The latter has already set-up the delegate and data source of its tableView to itself.

Comment: Functionally, Swift behaves no different than ObjectiveC. The power of Swift comes from the features of the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, that is completely independent of which language
you use, Swift or Objective-C.

But there are two different cases which may cause the confusion:

**A `UITableViewController` subclass:**

`UITableViewController` already conforms to `UITableViewDataSource`   and `UITableViewDelegate`. It has a `tableView` property, 
whose `dataSource` and `delegate` property are already set to `self`.

In your subclass, you typically *override* the
data source and delegate methods.

**A `UIViewController` subclass with a `UITableView` property:**

Here you have defined a `UITableView` property in your subclass
and initialize it in your code, or
connect it to a table view in the interface builder.

In this case you have to set the `dataSource` and `delegate`
property of the tableview, either in code or in the interface
builder, as explained in [luk2302's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34565603/1187415).

If data source and delegate are the view controller itself,
then you have to declare the protocol conformance explicitly,
and *implement* the
data source and delegate methods (but without *overriding*
a superclass method).

---

Of course, in both cases, the table view data source and the delegate
can be set to a *different* object, it does not have to be
the view controller itself.

Comment: Nice addition, I was not aware of the fact that a UITableViewController already is its own datasource and delegate - guess I have never subclassed one but always used a regular UIViewController.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, *some* assignment is still required.
Either explicitly via code

**OR**

What you can do instead is connect them already in the interface builder, making the explicit assignment via code obsolete. That is probably what a lot of tutorials do.

[image]