# Method does not override any method from it's superclass (error)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, overriding

I am coding a sidebar and I've got an error that I can't fix

Here is the code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell?   {
    var cell:UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as? UITableViewCell!

    if cell == nil{
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
```

I removed `override`but then I've got an other problem.

On this platform there is already a problem like this one.
But I didn't knew the solution after reading this.

Do you know what I have to do?

Comment: That probably means that your controller class is a subclass of UIViewController and not UITableViewController, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34565570/conforming-to-uitableviewdelegate-and-uitableviewdatasource-in-swift

Comment: Oh thx. I accidentally made a false class. Thx

Comment: Nope the same error again... But thx